# Can someone explain to me what this option is "Open Graph Image Url "?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I've Noticed that this field, "Open Graph Image Url", exists whenever you access the settings of a page in Magento 2.3.5 and I've no idea what it does. Can someone explain what it does to me or refer me to some guide that would help me understand the purpose of it?

[image: Open Graph Image Url]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically open graph is a protocol that is used to share web-page links on social media platforms in more fancy way. You may have seen something like this

[image: Sample Open Graph Share]

You only add your web-page link & it automatically creates a container with image, title, description etc. This magic can be accomplished by simply adding **open graph meta tags** in your web-page. Collect more info about open graph from https://ogp.me/.

Magento 2 has a native support to open graph protocol. So if you simply share link of any page on social media like FB / WhatsApp, it will create a container like shown in the above image.

In Magento, you have certain open graph configuration fields for pages like  Title, description, image URL etc. Now to answer your question, `Open Graph Image Url` field is used to specify the image to be shown while sharing the web-page link on social media platform using open graph protocol. It will create a open graph meta tag like below

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/ogp.jpg" />
```

Hope it was helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I do have a question though. Why is it that when I place an image URL, that exists within my server, in that field it doesn't show when I share the link?

Comment: There could be several possibilities. You need to debug a bit to get the exact reason. Here is a link which could help you to debug the reason. https://magefan.com/blog/why-sharing-link-does-not-show-image-on-facebook